How to return a nullable T from a generic method where T : notnull?
Consider this method in a project with nullable enabled:
public C? GetComponentOrNull<C>() where C : notnull;

The intent is that C is a non-nullable type (be it a value type, or a non-nullable reference type), but that the function returns a nullable version of that type.
But apparently it doesn't work the way I intend:
var component = GetComponentOrNull<int>();
if (component != null) {
    // ...
}

I get a warning on the null comparison:

The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type (CS0472) 'int?'

Hovering over the call site shows that the inferred return type is int, and not int? or Nullable<int> as I expected.
I tried writing Nullable<C> as the return type, instead of C?, but then I get an error:

The type 'C' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable' (CS0453)

What to do? Can I write this thing the way I wanted to?

Are you using enable on the project?

Of course. But I forgot to mention this. Editing.

Then why would you need to specify notnull? C is already not null.

I think because value types and reference types work differently, you either need two methods, or my preference would be a method signature like this public bool TryGetComponent<C>(out C? component) { ... }

@DavidG The .NET standard library seems to do it that way, so maybe it's the way to go. Feel free to post that as an answer.

See this answer which explains the behavior. In short if T is a value type, T and T? are the same type.

It seems that the ? nullable suffix is removed by the compiler when lowering the code which. You can see how this works here. Note how, in the lowered code, the method doesn't actually return a nullable value, and even the if statement is removed. However, if you constrain the generic type to be struct, the compiler now knows how to rewrite the code.
A safer, and (arguably) more readable way to write the code would be to borrow from how the BCL does this kind of thing and use a Try...(our T value) approach. For example:
public bool TryGetComponent<C>(out C? component)
{
    component = default!;
    return false;
}


Just to spell it out, the component parameter above will also be 0 when using <int> in this case, with or without where C : notnull, it's just that you no longer have to use the null vs non-null return value to indicate whether you got a component or not.

@LasseV.Karlsen Thanks, yes, great clarification.

This is the esoteric, ABSOLUTELY NOT RECOMMENDED answer. Feel free to downvote it into oblivion.
You can "trick" the compiler by adding two methods, but this is more like "Look how clever I am" than "This is how I would do it". I would absolutely go with the code in the answer by DavidG.
In any case, if you're into hurting yourself, here's some code:
var t = new Test();

t.GetComponentOrNull<int>();
t.GetComponentOrNull<string>();

public class Test
{
    public C? GetComponentOrNull<C>(C? dummy = default)
        where C : class
    {
        Console.WriteLine("returning class");
        return default;
    }

    public C? GetComponentOrNull<C>(C? dummy = default)
        where C : struct
    {
        Console.WriteLine("returning struct");
        return default;
    }
}

Prints out:
returning struct
returning class

The presence of the two dummy parameters trick the compiler into picking the right overload. You're of course soiling your method overloads with additional versions just to circumvent this, and you will also have this parameter show up in intellisense.
Again, NOT RECOMMENDED.

'?' has different meanings for class and struct types, so you have to use 2 methods separatly for class and struct, like public C? GetComponentOrNull<C>() where C : class and where C : struct.

Unfortunately the compiler won't allow that, because the two methods have the same signature (even if their generic constraints are not overlapping). I'd have to give them different names. I guess that works, but it's clunky. Leaving this question open in case someone has a more elegant answer...

@Thomas There are some hacks, but they are ABSOLUTELY NOT recommended. If you're really interested, you can try adding your two methods with where C : class and where C : struct, then tuck on a parameter with a default value to both methods: , C? dummy = default. This tricks the compiler into picking the right signature, but you're "soiling" the signatures with that extra parameter that you're not going to use.

@Lamp is correct. @Thomas: if you want gory details, look at this recent answer. For generic types, CLR permits no workaround. For methods, though, Lasse's workaround - overloaded methods with a dummy parameter - works, and I would totally go for it. I use similar dummy parameters to work around deficiencies in C# compiler's generic type deduction engine.

@Thomas, the trick is put the result as out parameter instead of return, GetComponentOrNull<C>(out C? value)
